# Why would my react app send cookies in development but not in production

Tags: reactjs, node.js, session, cookies

Actually my react app sends cookies while in development but it doesn't in production. My production host is https://www.blahblah.com
This is how I set my nodejs backend.

```
app.use(
  session({
    store: new pgSession({
      pool: db,
      tableName: "session",
      schemaName: "public",
    }),
    secret: "sequential",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 3600000, //1 hour
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
    }, // 1 hour
  })
);
```

Comment: You should always set the samesite attribute as well, I did post a blog post about diagnosing cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/